# Download file from Azure blob storage onto Azure Linux VM

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli

I'm coming from an AWS background and trying to get something relatively simple to work in Azure, but currently having a rough time parsing through all the documentation and Microsoft-specific jargon to find what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to download a single file I have in Azure blob storage (which from what I can gather is the closest equivalent to storing an object in S3) onto a Linux VM with the CLI. From what I've read. the command I need to run is:

```
az storage copy -s https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myfile -d .
```

A couple of questions for automation purposes, however. Is there an equivalent to IAM roles for VMs in Azure? That way, I won't have to keep credential file(s) on the VM itself. But if not, what type of credentials should I generate for best practice? I ask, because it seems there's about a half-dozen different choices in Azure, and all I'm really looking for is something basic. Just essentially need what amounts to a "programmatic-access only" user in AWS. That way I can also lock down its permissions to a very specific set of resources and/or actions.

As always, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an equivalent to IAM roles for VMs in Azure?

What you're looking for is [`Managed Identity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview). Basically the way it works is that you assign an identity to your Azure resource (a Linux VM in your case) so that your Azure resource behaves like any other user in your Azure AD and then assign appropriate role/access to that user.

You can learn more about Managed Identities in Azure here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview.

Comment: Thanks! After some more head-banging today, I finally figured out what works for my case --
-Create User-Assigned Managed Identity (Managed Identities in Portal)
-Assign UAMI to VM(s) (VM page -> Identity -> User assigned tab in Portal)
-Go to blob container -> Access control (IAM) -> Add role assignment -> Select the UAMI -> "Storage Blob Data Reader" permissions
-On VM and run: 'az login --identity -u [Client ID of UAMI]' then 'az storage blob download --auth-mode login --account-name [storage-account-name] --container-name [container-name] --file [out-file] --name [blob-file-name]'